# why data().join() behave differently on g elements with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i have a function that accepts different data arrays and draw a treemap using d3.js

the structure require a g element with a rect and text in it
so for every data node there is a g element to group rect and text
and i use join() to keep the elements on the screen linked to the datasets i pass in

strangly when running something like :

```
svg.selectAll("g").data(myDataArray).join("g").append("rect")
```

it works fine and the g binds to `myDataArray` nodes except the first g

the first g never changes instead it gets filled with rect elements anytime i pass a different `myDataArray` and the rest of the g elements just works as intended and gets the new data displayed in them and the old gets removed except the first element
on the other hand when i test it using other elements say i do this :

```
svg.selectAll("div").data(myDataArray).join("div").append("h1");
```

every thing works as intended and every data node gets a div with h1 inside showing the data
and also the first div update its h1 unlike the first g element that just keep adding rect elements inside it everytime `myDataArray` gets changed
i have tried so many different ways to debug but couldnt understand why this thing happen on g elements but not other type of containers

Comment: Both of these snippets should work in exactly the same way. Maybe you're doing something else that's not visible here. Share a working example (in a fiddle or a codepen) to help it easier to understand the issue.

Comment: This `svg.selectAll("g")` might not be what you think it is. You're selecting every group under `svg`, which typically is all the contents of your viz (axis, titles, etc).

Comment: when i do this the effect in question happen 
```svg.selectAll("g").data(myDataArray,(d)=>d).join("g").append("rect");```